# Get shopping cart ID given customer ID

Tags: magento-1.7, api, magento-1.7.0.1

I'm trying to get the shopping cart ID given the customer ID, to expose it by SOAP API.

Calling the web service with an ID 1 returns nothing.

What am I missing here?

**Here's the code for the web service**

```
public function getShoppingCartId($customerId)
{
    Mage::log(__METHOD__);

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer = $customer->load($customerId);

    Mage::log('Getting shopping cart of '. $customer->getName() .' ('. $customer->getEmail() .'), ID: ' . $customer->getId() );

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);

    Mage::log("-------------------------------------------");
    return $quote->getId();
}
```

**This is the log output**

```
DEBUG (7): Phoenix_Moneybookers_Model_Core_Api::getShoppingCartId
DEBUG (7): Getting shopping cart of John Doe (john.doe@example.com), ID: 1
DEBUG (7): -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is not use the `loadByCustomer` function that is found in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` but simply build your own collection with the correct filters.

```
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection $quoteCollection */
$quoteCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();
$quoteCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', 4);
```

This will get you all quotes ever for this customer. You can then filter by `updated_at` date to get the the most recent first and then select only one.

```
$quoteCollection->addOrder('updated_at');
$quote = $quoteCollection->getFirstItem();
```

This will give you the most recent quote object for this customer. This way you do not need to rewrite anything.

Comment: @David Manners can i add also $quoteCollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);

Answer (score 1):

Your Quote is  `currently at inactive stage`.As per magento when we try to load a quote using `customer(i.e loadByCustomer())` it only `given the one active quote object`.

**See: at Class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote**

```
 public function loadByCustomer($customer)
    {
        if ($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) {
            $customerId = $customer->getId();
        }
        else {
            $customerId = (int) $customer;
        }
        $this->_getResource()->loadByCustomerId($this, $customerId);
        $this->_afterLoad();
        return $this;
    }
```

**and Class Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote**

```
 public function loadByCustomerId($quote, $customerId)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
        $select  = $this->_getLoadSelect('customer_id', $customerId, $quote)
            ->where('is_active = ?', 1)
            ->order('updated_at ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC)
            ->limit(1);

        $data    = $adapter->fetchRow($select);

        if ($data) {
            $quote->setData($data);
        }

        $this->_afterLoad($quote);

        return $this;
    }
```

### Solution:

rewrite class  `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote`  and remove is_active clause function loadByCustomerId.

```
 public function loadByCustomerId($quote, $customerId)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
        $select  = $this->_getLoadSelect('customer_id', $customerId, $quote)
          //  ->where('is_active = ?', 1)
            ->order('updated_at ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC)
            ->limit(1);

        $data    = $adapter->fetchRow($select);

        if ($data) {
            $quote->setData($data);
        }

        $this->_afterLoad($quote);

        return $this;
    }
```

**Note: It is not a good idea.**

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree with you that is not a good idea to mess with magento's core code.